# Puppeteer: waitForFunction sometimes never resolves

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have simple Puppeteer script:

```
await page.goto(MY_URL, {waitUntil: 'load'});
const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
```

Then I check if html contains some key strings and this part always pass (I mentioned in case if this could anyhow influence further process).
Abd after that, I wait for a function to be included in `window` object.

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => 'myFunction' in window);
```

This function is written at the bottom of the script attached in `<head>` by `<script>` tag of the page.
Mostly, `waitForFunction` resolves as it should, but sometimes it doesn't.
And when I pass `{timeout: 0}` it gonna wait forever and never resolves.
It also seems that this happen only in headless mode.

What could be the cause of such a behavior? How to overcome or debug such issue?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that JavaScript files sometimes weren't loaded.
The solution for me was:

```
await page.goto(MY_URL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
```